# NiFi block flowfile when failure

Tags: apache-nifi

I set a Processor failure relationship to itself, when a flowfile process failed, I    want it back to top of the incoming queue and retry again, also I send an email notification to administrator, after failure solved, the blocked flowfiles can be able to process aggin. Does NiFi support this ?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can drag multiple relationships from a processor, so you can have one *failure* connection that points back to itself and one *failure* connection that goes to a `PutEmail` processor which sends a notification to the administrator. If you want to prioritize the failed flowfile, you can use a *funnel* component to join the incoming queue with the *failure* queue and create a single joined queue with a prioritizer for "last in, first out".